# Why find() using models won't work in signup route?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

It's a simple signup route to store credentials in a mongoDB database but I miss something because the 2 `else if` won't work properly. I suspect it is my `find()`.

The first `else if` returns me in Postman `"error": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: vinted.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: \"jean@dpont.com\" }"` and the second give me `"email already exists".`

Thanks in advance for your help

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");
const encBase64 = require("crypto-js/enc-base64");
const uid2 = require("uid2");

const User = require("../models/User");

router.post("/user/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const email = req.fields.email;
    const username = req.fields.username;
    const phone = req.fields.phone;
    const password = req.fields.password;
    const token = uid2(64);
    const salt = uid2(16);
    const hash = SHA256(password + salt).toString(encBase64);

    const emailSearch = await User.find({ email: email });
    if (!emailSearch || username !== null) {
      const newUser = new User({
        email: email,
        account: {
          username: username,
          phone: phone,
        },
        password: password,
        token: token,
        hash: hash,
        salt: salt,
      });
      await newUser.save();
      res.status(200).json({
        _id: newUser._id,
        token: newUser.token,
        account: newUser.account,
      });
    }
   //problem under
    else if (emailSearch) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "email already exists" });
    } else if (username === null) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "please type a username" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that if the username in the request body is not `null`, it's going to attempt to create a new User with that username regardless of whether a User exists with the same email - `if (!emailSearch || username !== null)`.

It's generally best-practice to do as much input validation as you can before you start looking for records or creating new ones, as you will be able to avoid more Mongo errors and database actions if you can stop invalid actions before they're attempted. So in this case, check that the username is valid before looking for existing Users.

To solve this problem, I would move that last `else-if` to before you check whether a User exists with the same email. That way, once you determine whether the username is valid, then the only thing that you need to consider is existing Users before creating a new one. Something like this:

```
if (username === null) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Error: Please provide a 'username'." });
}

const existingUserWithEmail = await User.find({ email: email });
if (!existingUserWithEmail) {
    // Create the new User
} else {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Error: An account already exists with this email." });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer with your proposal.